# Using control arrays in c# .net

Tags: c#, arrays, controls

I am creating a menu with big buttons containing an image, and text. When selected a border is around the button.

The button text is not always the same, and the result of the button click neither.

I have the image name, and text per button set in a struct like this: (there are four of them, but i'll show 2)

```
struct ConfigDevSubmenu
    {

        public const string SubMenuBtnText1 = "";
        public const string SubMenuBtnText2 = "text submenu 3 button 1";
        public const string SubMenuBtnText3 = "text submenu 3 button 2";
        public const string SubMenuBtnText4 = "";
        public const string SubMenuBtnImg1 = null;
        public const string SubMenuBtnImg2 = "Settings.png";
        public const string SubMenuBtnImg3 = "LoadFirmware.png";
        public const string SubMenuBtnImg4 = null;
        public const string SubMenuBtnBorder1 = "Borderstyle.None";
        public const string SubMenuBtnBorder2 = "Borderstyle.FixedSingle";
        public const string SubMenuBtnBorder3 = "Borderstyle.FixedSingle";
        public const string SubMenuBtnBorder4 = "Borderstyle.None";
    }
    struct AdvancedSubmenu
    {
        public const string SubMenuBtnText1 = "text submenu 4 button 1";
        public const string SubMenuBtnText2 = "text submenu 4 button 2";
        public const string SubMenuBtnText3 = "text submenu 4 button 3";
        public const string SubMenuBtnText4 = "text submenu 4 button 4";
        public const string SubMenuBtnImg1 = "GenerateEncKey.png";
        public const string SubMenuBtnImg2 = "Monitoring.png";
        public const string SubMenuBtnImg3 = "AdvancedSettings.png";
        public const string SubMenuBtnImg4 = "GenerateConfigFile.png";
        public const string SubMenuBtnBorder1 = "Borderstyle.FixedSingle";
        public const string SubMenuBtnBorder2 = "Borderstyle.FixedSingle";
        public const string SubMenuBtnBorder3 = "Borderstyle.FixedSingle";
        public const string SubMenuBtnBorder4 = "Borderstyle.FixedSingle";
    }
```

I do not think this can be done much easier without using database files.

To create the buttons I have this function which has as argument the which struct it should use, and in a switch case structure each button is created. 
But I've found myself copy-pasting alot in these functions so this must be possible easier. Therefore I tried something like below, but that does not work. I'd like to know whether it is possible to make that work, and how I should do that.

```
    private void createButtons(string Struct)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
        {
            SubBtnText[i].Text = Struct.SubMenuBtnText[i];
            pictureBoxSubBtn[i].Image = Image.FromFile(Struct.SubMenuBtnImg[i]);
            panelSubBtn[i].BorderStyle = Struct.SubMenuBtnBorder[i];

        }
    }
```

Any suggetions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a class to hold the button text, image name and border styles - say `ButtonData`.

Create several *lists* (or arrays) of `ButtonData`, one per menu.

You can then iterate over the lists and extract the data.

```
public class ButtonData
{
   public ButtonData(string text, string image, BorderStyle border)
   {
       Text = text;
       Image = image;
       Border = border;
   }

   public string Text { get; private set; }
   public string Image { get; private set; }
   public BorderStyle Border { get; private set; }
}

var devMenuData = new List<ButtonData> { 
                                  new ButtonData("", null, "Borderstyle.None"), 
                                  new ButtonData("text submenu 3 button 1",
                                                 "Settings.png",
                                                 Borderstyle.FixedSingle), 
                                  ...
                                       };
```

Your function would something like:

```
private void CreateButtons(IEnumerable<ButtonData> data)
{
    foreach (var buttonData in data)
    {
        SubBtnText[i].Text = buttonData.Text;
        pictureBoxSubBtn[i].Image = Image.FromFile(buttonData.Image);
        panelSubBtn[i].BorderStyle = buttonData.Border;
    }
}
```

The above amended function will not work as such, as .NET doesn't have control arrays. You could create *another* list/array to iterate over or index through for this to work.

Comment: Some tweaks on this did the trick, I am not really sure this is better than I had, but I learned from it :)

Answer (score 0):

[reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

```
class ButtonParameters
{
    public string SubMenuBtnText = string.Empty;
    public string SubMenuBtnImg = string.Empty;
    public string SubMenuBtnBorder = string.Empty;
}

public Dictionary<int, ButtonParameters> CreateParameters(Type type)
{
    FieldInfo[] fieldInfos = type.GetFields(
        BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
    Dictionary<int, ButtonParameters> parameters = new Dictionary<int, ButtonParameters>();
    foreach (FieldInfo fieldInfo in fieldInfos)
    {
        if (fieldInfo.Name.Contains("SubMenuBtnText"))
        {
            int index = Convert.ToInt32(fieldInfo.Name.Substring(14));
            if (!parameters.ContainsKey(index))
            {
                parameters.Add(index, new ButtonParameters());
            }
            parameters[index].SubMenuBtnText = (string)fieldInfo.GetValue(null);
        }
        else if (fieldInfo.Name.Contains("SubMenuBtnImg"))
        {
            int index = Convert.ToInt32(fieldInfo.Name.Substring(13));
            if (!parameters.ContainsKey(index))
            {
                parameters.Add(index, new ButtonParameters());
            }
            parameters[index].SubMenuBtnImg=  (string)fieldInfo.GetValue(null);
        }
        else if (fieldInfo.Name.Contains("SubMenuBtnBorder"))
        {
            int index = Convert.ToInt32(fieldInfo.Name.Substring(16));
            if (!parameters.ContainsKey(index))
            {
                parameters.Add(index, new ButtonParameters());
            }
            parameters[index].SubMenuBtnBorder= (string)fieldInfo.GetValue(null);
        }
    }
    return parameters;
}

private void createButtons()
{
    Dictionary<int, ButtonParameters> buttons = CreateParameters(typeof(AdvancedSubmenu));
    for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
    {
        SubBtnText[i].Text = buttons[i].SubMenuBtnText;
        pictureBoxSubBtn[i].Image = Image.FromFile(buttons[i].SubMenuBtnImg);
        panelSubBtn[i].BorderStyle = buttons[i].SubMenuBtnBorder;
    }
}
```